# 32 bit applications on 64 bit OS ( windows )

Tags: windows, iis, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I need some help understanding how 32 bit applications use memory on a 64 bit OS.

A 32 bit application can use 2 gb of memory on 64 bit OS, correct?
Does this mean that 3 32 bit applications running in parrallel could address 6 gb of memory...
Or do the 3 32 bit applications have to share the 2-4 gb of 32 bit memory that the os has?

Likewise, If I have a webservice that is compiled as 32 bits, running under IIS on a 64 bit machine. As long as a single request to that webservice always stays under 2gb of memory usage, is there any point in recompiling to 64 bit? My theory is that IIS creates a new process for each request, so the whole pool of processes will be able to make use of all the memory the 64bit machine has , 8 or 15 or 20 gig or whatever.

Let me know your thoughts, thanks

Comment: Since there already is a good answer, just a comment: Yes, compiling 32bit code means the address space available to the application is limited (theoretically) to 4GB (2GB on Windows, unless you enable  [large address awareness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586826/image-file-large-address-aware-and-3gb-os-switch)). The application address space can be located anywhere within your 8 or 15 or 20 gig of memory. Consequently, several processess can coexist each having their own 2GB of address space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the total usage of all the 32-bit programs can exceed 2 GB. So yes you can have a bunch of 32-bit processes using all the memory in a 64-bit machine.

Actually, there's a compiler option that lets 32-bit programs use up to 3GB in Windows.
If performance isn't important, then there isn't much of a reason to use 64-bit.

Comment: It is 4GB on a 64-bit operating system.  Total usage can easily exceed 2 or 4GB on a 32-bit operating system as well.  The missing ingredient is *virtual* memory.